# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

Tags: java

I am using bcpkix-jdk15on-151.jar for PEMParser.java class and oracle java 7,

But at line

PEMParser pemRd = new PEMParser(fRd);

I got following exeption

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sarang.test.CertificateLoader.getCertificate(CertificateLoader.java:24)
    at com.sarang.test.CertificateLoader.main(CertificateLoader.java:43)
```

my source code is :

```
public static X509Certificate getCertificate() throws IOException {
        String pemfile = "/home/sarang07/keys/key1.crt";
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = null;

        try {
            FileReader fRd = new FileReader(pemfile);
            PEMParser pemRd = new PEMParser(fRd);

            Object o;
            o = pemRd.readPemObject();
            if (o instanceof java.security.cert.X509Certificate)
            {
                cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) o;
            } else {
                throw new IOException("fail to load certificate from file " + pemfile);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException("Can't find file " + pemfile);
        }

        return cert;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution from below code snippet...

```
public static java.security.cert.X509Certificate getCertificate(String pemfile) throws Exception
{
    java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = null;
    try {
        FileReader fRd = new FileReader(pemfile);
        final PemReader certReader = new PemReader(fRd);
        final PemObject certAsPemObject = certReader.readPemObject();
        if (!certAsPemObject.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CERTIFICATE")) {
            throw new Exception("Certificate file does not contain a certificate but a " + certAsPemObject.getType());
        }
        final byte[] x509Data = certAsPemObject.getContent();
        final CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        cert = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(x509Data));
        if (!(cert instanceof X509Certificate)) {
            throw new Exception("Certificate file does not contain an X509 certificate");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IOException("Can't find file " + pemfile);
    }
    return cert;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably having a dependency conflict-
Do you have 2 versions of the above mentioned jar in the path?
Maybe you are adding the dependency in the POM file and also adding another veriosn of the jar to your build?

Comment: no i have only used only this versoin bcpkix-jdk15on-151.jar on my path